# Using a String that contains operators as a variable on an if-statement

Tags: java, android

Title is self-explanatory.

Instead of using:

```
if (link.contains(".com") || (link.contains(".net") || (link.contains(".org") || (link.contains(".info") || ("etc there are many domain names")) {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www." + link);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www." + link + ".com");
}
```

I want to do it this way if possible by declaring the String's values globally.

```
if (link.contains(domainNames)) {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www." + link);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www." + link + ".com");
}
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110563/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-has-a-substring-from-a-list

Comment: It is a bit unclear. You want to check which domain is in specific url without entering domains manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a regex with the domain names, then test it, e.g.

```
private static final Pattern DOMAIN_NAMES = Pattern.compile("\\.(?i:com|net|org|info)$");
```

```
if (DOMAIN_NAMES.matcher(link).find()) {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www." + link);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www." + link + ".com");
}
```

Comment: Be warned, this is very error prone if two url endings happen to have mostly matching parts as a regex like e.g. `(a|abc)` will never match `abc` as the first alternatives consumes the `a` only leaving the `bc` to match, which won't happen now! You have to order your endings by length to avoid this issue

Comment: @roookeee You are wrong, since the regex **backtracking** will ensure that `(a|abc)$` will match any string ending in `a` or `abc`. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HJU7Mq/1) for proof.

Comment: You are right, when using `$` this doesn't matter. It only matters in cases where one wants to have the most exact match (without using `$` at the end) as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/gCjPie/1)

Comment: This worked great. I use voice input to fill "link", it might be my imagination but i think voice searches are more accurate than before? anyway this is awesome...

Answer (score 0):

Another mannual approach could be :
Domainnamelist.contains(substring from link that contains domain ending)